# ngx-translate not working after I added LoadingInterceptor

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate, httpinterceptor

I'm using ngx-translate and now I would like to add a LoadingInterceptor. So an HTTPInterceptor that shows a LoadingSpinner when an API request is made.

I am already using a token interceptor.
But when I install the LoadingInterceptor, ngx-translate no longer works.

Here is my loading.interceptor.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
// import { LoadingService } from './../../../services/loading.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    // Liste von Requests
    private requests: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];

    constructor() {}

    public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('detect request', request.url);
        return new Observable(observer => {

        });
    }

}
```

And this is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Translate
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

// Interceptors
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './interceptors/token.interceptor';
import { LoadingInterceptor } from './interceptors/loading.interceptor';

// tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'de',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
    }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    [
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: LoadingInterceptor,
        multi: true
      },
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: TokenInterceptor,
        multi: true
      }
    ],

    TranslateService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my html tag with the variable to be translated:

```
<span>{{ 'TEST' | translate }}</span>
```

And this is the de.json file from my i18n folder:

```
{
    "TEST": "Hello world"
}
```

I don't get an error message, the variable to be translated is simply no longer displayed. Unless I comment out the LoadingInterceptor in the app.module.ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intercept` method should always return the reponse in some way, your interceptor is simply returning a new Observable, which obviously doesn't contain the translation anymore (ngx-translate gets its translations from .json, which is also intercepted by interceptors).

```
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('detect request', request.url);
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

This interceptor simply returns the original request without modifying it (No-op)